# Where in the pdf text did the modification likely take place?

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf file that was created on a certain date and from the meta-data it was last modified on a date after its creation.

The pdf is nearly all just text and there is a sentence in the text that has likely been extended and a word deleted. Can I find out whether this particular sentence was in fact (likely) modified between the creation date and last modification date? Or rule it out.

I didn't know whether I could convert the pdf to a more elementary type (similar to .tex) or view it in another more elementary application (like CosEdit) to identify whether this sentence was extended and words deleted between the creation date and last modification date?

Don't worry about anyone attempting to conceal the modifications in any way. That's not applicable in this instance.

Link to document: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OFXRCw2U1mo7BjHUSGs_1fVjDsQLRo0V/view?usp=drivesdk

Realvent line is on page5. Its the first bullet point under the title Criteria for Addressing a Property

Comment: Can you share the pdf in question

Comment: I've added a link to the PDF file

Answer (score 0):

There is **not much value or certainty** when analysing a reasonably well constructed PDF the sample provided is of unknown pedigree. I personally would not trust a PDF history comparison over a conventional Paper Trail. You query the changes made to a newer copy of a Public Document.

We can see the Original was reported as produced by the technician using Word 2013 on 6/12/2017, potentially after drafts had been corrected by management, the source document reports that there were 2 prior changes, which are not of concern here, since the document as it stood at that time, would then (as if printed) have gone forward for final approval, master sign off, and publication.

You provided a secondary amended copy of the same policy document. Initial query shows it appears as if it was subject to A change in time but there are no incremental editions to be pared back, so using a comparison tool we can check for the differences.

First look suggests 5 of 8 pages were changed (updated per annual review)

The first change is Page 3 the admin charge for 2021 is now £86 (was £75 in 2017)

The second change is on Page 5 more on that later

The third change is on Page 6 where premise has been changed to primary

The fourth is Page 7 where the example Numbered ... 1 is changed to Lettered ... A

Finally Page 8 the Technician has been Promoted over the years and the department has been renamed.

ALL these changes would have been made in the source Word Document which in turn may have changed many more times than we shall know without the paper trail showing which day the technician was formally appointed or the department changed name or the annual charges were increased. A PDF is dumbly generated as showing A difference  from the original.

Your query is can we tell how many times or when or by who Page 5 was changed. As you may have gathered from the above the short answer is usually no (not from a PDF).
The changes over time of a policy document are driven by many factors such as inflation, spell checking and proof reading changes, or changes in managerial policies.

Page 5 was changed in two places
semantically the unnecessary word "new" was replaced with "a"
and a concession was added to the end of the paragraph
"unless justification can be supplied"

There is no way of knowing who penned those changes, only some certainty we can guess the technician was directed to make those corrections between 2017 and 2021. But was it verbal or by email or paper we do not know those are other documents. What we do know is the final document must have been approved for PDF printing, unless your copy is unofficial.

If you wish to know more see https://www.whatdotheyknow.com/request/street_naming_information